# How create this wpf toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolbar

I would like to create a toolbar like this on wpf.

[image]

What i need to use in order to create the area with the button circled in red ? 
Is it possible with the microsoft toolbar ?

For the moment i tried this :

[image]

Here is my xaml code :

```
    <ToolBarTray Background="#008ede" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" >
        <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Background="#008ede" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Button Name="tbrClear" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Name="Image1"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="tbrClear_" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="_XWPF_TBR_PRECED.PNG_IMAGES.png" Name="Image2"></Image>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>    
    </ToolBarTray>
```

1) First, i would like to know how centered the button, i add the verticalAlignment="Center", but nothing is center. Have you an idea please?

2) Secondly, how remove or hide the little rectangle white on the right please ?

3) Then, anyone know how it's possible to recreate the area circled on red please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

Your tool bar looks centered.  do you mean you want the toolbar to be where the caption/title is or do you want to hide the caption title?  for the latter you can try WindowStyle="None" in your window.

As for for the 'little rectangle" try getting and setting OverflowGrid visibility property of the toolbar.

you probably also need to wrap the elments in  aborder and use the corner radius to achieve the rounded corners. here's an example:

```
    <DockPanel  Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" Margin="1" Background="#008ede">
                <ToolBarTray Background="#008ede" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                    <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Background="Transparent"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Name="tbrClear" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Name="Image1"></Image>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Name="tbrClear_" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="_XWPF_TBR_PRECED.PNG_IMAGES.png" Name="Image2"></Image>
                        </Button>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ToolBarTray>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: My toolbar is not centered on my ToolbarTray. Then,you said "Try getting and setting Overflow visibility property of the toolbar", but i don't have an OverFlowGrid property.

Comment: ok. on my toolbartray, i use "VerticalAlignment = 'Stretch'".

Comment: I tried it but there's no change. I will look for this probleme after. Could you explain me please how create the rectangle with corner radius on the toolbar( for grouping button) please ? It will be very nice :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's better ! My buttons are centered :). For the rectangle with the corner radius, i'm telling about the rectangle circled in red on my picture ( the black rectangle behind the button), do you know if it's possible ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: i already edited my post w/ to provide an example of how to make a rounded corner.

Comment: Maybe it's not a toolbar and a juste a stackpanel/border !